# Approximation of a sum by an integral

Tags: reference-request, summation

Is there a good reference on the approximation of sums using integrals ?

I am familiar with Riemann sums, and with the Euler-Maclaurin formula.

Still, many times when doing a probability calculation, I encounter a sum (actually the limit of a sum) which I cannot force into either of the above.

Here's an example:
$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=-C \sqrt{n}}^{C \sqrt{n}} e^{-a \frac{j^2}{n} + b \frac{j}{\sqrt{n}}}$$
where $j$ runs over all the integers in the interval $[-C\sqrt{n},C\sqrt{n}]$.

Comment: Please, add some examples

Comment: This question and the answers provide another summation method for integrals, maybe it might be useful https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3265474/269624

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think with some tinkering your example could be turned into a Riemann sum. Is this a very typical example? Sums of the kind $\sum_j e^{-a j^2+b j}$ are related to Jacobi theta functions