# Prove a new digamma finite sum

Tags: integration, summation, euler-mascheroni-constant, digamma-function

There are a few interesting finite sums of digamma of a rational argument listed on Wikipedia (from [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X14002820?via%3Dihub)). One of them is the following:

$$\sum _{m=1}^{N-1}\psi \left({\frac {m}{N}}\right)\cdot {\frac {m}{N}}=-{\frac {\gamma }{2}}(N-1)-{\frac {N}{2}}\log N-{\frac {\pi }{2}}\sum _{m=1}^{N-1}{\frac {m}{N}}\cdot \cot {\frac {\pi m}{N}}$$

I found a related sum with Mathematica, using numerical experiments (linear fit actually helped):

> $$\sum _{m=1}^{2N-1}(-1)^m \frac {m}{2N} \left[ \psi \left(\frac {m}{2N}\right)+\frac {\pi }{2} \cot \frac {\pi m}{2N} \right] =\frac {\gamma }{2}+ N \log 2$$

[image]

**I still would like to prove this**, and the linked paper could probably help, but it's quite long and complicated, so if anyone has better ideas, I'd like to hear them.

I suppose we can use:

$$\pi z \cot \pi z=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{z}{n+z}-\frac{z}{n-z}\right)-1$$

$$z \psi (z)=-\gamma z +\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left({\frac {z}{n+1}}-{\frac {z}{n+z}}\right)$$

I wanted this formula because of the method of exhaustion, referenced in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3265474/269624):

$$\int_0^1f(x)\,dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^{2^n-1}\frac{(-1)^m}{2^n}f\left(\frac m{2^n}\right)$$

Though I'm far from finished with the original proof I needed it for, I found an interesting consequence:

> $$\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi)=-\sum _{n=1}^\infty \sum _{m=1}^{2^n-1} \frac{(-1)^m m }{2^n} \left(\frac{1}{2^n} \left( \frac{ \pi}{2}  \cot \left(\frac{\pi  m}{2^n}\right)+\gamma \right)+\log (2)\right)$$

Since:

$$-\int_0^1 u \psi(u) du=\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi)$$

---

As an additional question, the odd sum also appears to be approximately linear, so if anyone has ideas:

$$\sum _{m=1}^{2N}(-1)^m \frac {m}{2N+1} \left[ \psi \left(\frac {m}{2N+1}\right)-\frac {\pi }{2} \cot \frac {\pi m}{2N+1} \right] -\frac {\gamma }{2}= ?$$

---

Turns out, there's a more general relation for digammas of rational arguments ($m<N$) (see Wikipedia):

$$\psi \left({\frac {m}{N}}\right)=-\gamma -\log (2N)-\frac {\pi }{2} \cot \left(\frac {\pi m }{N}\right)+2\sum _{n=1}^{\left\lfloor {\frac {N-1}{2}}\right\rfloor }\cos \left({\frac {2\pi n m}{N}}\right)\ln \sin \left({\frac {\pi n}{N}}\right)$$

Which clearly can be used to derive more finite sums. However, it's quite complicated, so I haven't yet managed to derive my result.

Comment: I read you question with much interest, because I'm currently working on a new digamma infinite sum. The only hint I have for you - lack of time - is
$$\frac{1}{2} \left(\psi \left(-\frac{m}{2 N}\right)-\psi \
\left(\frac{m}{2 N}\right)\right)=\frac{N}{m}+\frac{1}{2} \pi  \
\cot \left(\frac{\pi m}{2 N}\right)$$
$$\sum _{m=1}^{2 N-1} \frac{(-1)^m m \left(\psi \left(1+\frac{m}{2 N}\
\right)+\psi \left(1-\frac{m}{2 N}\right)\right)}{4 N}+\frac{1}{2}=N \
\log (2)+\frac{\gamma}{2}$$

Comment: @stocha, thank you, this is useful

Comment: you welcome. In the proof I got also these terms Log2 and EulerGamma, I am working on the Laplace Transform of a complex valued psi-function.

Comment: @stocha: Were these sums published somewhere? I would see the derivation.

Comment: @granularbastard: It is a long time ago an I did not exactly remember the way to evaluate the sums.  They come from Laplace transform of the complex valued digamma function, which I did not published yet. I would use the Mellin transform representation (Ederlyi 7.3.49 p.353) $$\Psi(s+a)-\Psi(s+b)=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}g(x)\,dx$$

Comment: where

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^b-x^a}{1-x} &\mbox{if } 0<x<1 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x> 1 \end{cases}
$$

and  $\Re s>-\Re a,-\Re b$.